# How can I resolve the issue where, in iOS 17, audio plays through the earpiece instead of the speaker when the camera loads?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

In my PWA app, I utilize the getUserMedia() API for accessing the camera and also employ HTML audio tags to handle various types of media content. However, since updating to iOS 17, I've encountered an issue where, after granting permission for camera access, audio playback occurs through the earpiece instead of the media speaker. This problem is specific to iOS 17; earlier iOS versions work as expected.

My app is developed using a stack that includes JavaScript, Angular, Ionic, HTML5, and CSS. Can you please provide guidance or a solution to address this issue and ensure that audio plays through the media speaker when using the camera on iOS 17?

Comment: check this link: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/multi/

Comment: Are you able to solve the issue or any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're providing a solution to a specific issue related to the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() method in JavaScript. Removing the return statement from navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() in the code might be a solution for your particular problem.

However, it's important to note that this solution will only be applicable in cases where the return value of navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() is not needed or relevant to the functionality of your code. If you have a specific question or need help with a related issue, please provide more context or details so I can assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to have been fixed in iOS 17.2.1.